# How to connect the Windows Phone 8.1 app to Fabric Crashlytics?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, crashlytics

Is there **any way** to connect the Windows Phone 8.1 application to [Fabric  Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/)?

I found [these plugins](https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin), that are for iOS and Android only, but I'm looking for the one for Windows Phone.

Is there any way I can connect to that plaftorm?

EDIT: this question is not opinion-based. The answer can be easily validated.

Comment: I haven't used this, but you can try to see if this NuGet package works: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Crashlytics/

Comment: @Barnstokkr It's for Xamarin only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Fabric Crashlytics` are not available for windows phone apps. You may try some other `Crashlytics` services providers such as the [HockeyApp](https://www.hockeyapp.net/features/). I used it for my app, the service is entirely free for a single app.